# Pingouin mixed anova not reporting Greenhouse-Geisser corrected p-values

Tags: python, mixed-models, pingouin

I am running a mixed model anova using Pingouin, but I can't get it to report the Greenhouse-Geisser corrected p-values

My data is structured like this:

| user_id | Groups | test_id | avg_payment | variable | value | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21000010749909 | control | 1 | 0 | avg_daily_net_rev | 0 | before |
| 21000021190553 | control | 1 | 0-9 | avg_daily_net_rev | 80 | before |
| 21000021497845 | control | 1 | 9-40 | avg_daily_net_rev | 48 | before |
| 21000020054046 | test | 1 | 40-80 | avg_daily_net_rev | 14 | before |
| 21000021354449 | control | 1 | 80-100 | avg_daily_net_rev | 7 | before |
| 21000010749909 | control | 1 | 0 | avg_daily_net_rev | 0 | after |
| 21000021190553 | control | 1 | 0-9 | avg_daily_net_rev | 76 | after |
| 21000021497845 | control | 1 | 9-40 | avg_daily_net_rev | 30 | after |
| 21000020054046 | test | 1 | 40-80 | avg_daily_net_rev | 48 | after |
| 21000021354449 | control | 1 | 80-100 | avg_daily_net_rev | 71 | after |

And my code like this

```
def AOV(var, hom, norm, spher, data):
    temp_var = data[data["variable"] == var]
    aov = pg.mixed_anova(dv='value',
                         between='Groups',
                         within='Condition',
                         subject='user_id',
                         effsize="ng2",
                         correction='True',
                         data=temp_var)
    return aov
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using `correction=True` instead of `correction='True'`